# Specifying a full topology with MediaFoundation

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I've created a topology for a video file which contains just one stream (no audio).

It contains three nodes which are connected in order:

- a source stream node
- an `Mpeg4Part2VideoDecoder` as transform node
- an [activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object for the EVR as output node

Calling [SetTopology()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), allowing for a partial topology results in working playback. However, I am trying to resolve the full topology myself.

Therefore, [I first need to bind my output node to a media sink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb250383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I followed the guidelines specified in the manual, and all the required calls seem to succeed. When setting the full topology, I receive the [`MESessionTopologySet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event.

Unfortunately, playback doesn't work, but I don't get any errors.

- **Is there anything else required when creating a full topology?**
- I recall reading somewhere in the msdn docs that the topology loader which is used when setting a partial topology also sets media types. Is this required, and if so where can I find more information on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt Andrews [answered this one for me on the msdn forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mediafoundationdevelopment/thread/20615e4e-adb7-4169-821c-4c1e00eff0b1).

> You definitely need to negotiate your own media types if you are
>   bypassing the topology loader.  This means obtaining the source's
>   media type from IMFMediaTypeHandler, setting it on the downstream
>   transform, and then for each node down the chain, querying the
>   available input and output types to find a compatible media type.  It
>   is much easier to use the topoloader unless you have a specific need
>   to avoid it.

Comment: A word of warning, I didn't test this myself yet though. I just used a partial topology instead.